# Spring Tools with JavaScript

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to connect my javascript file to my webpage and I can not even though it's connecting the right way.

Watch the image

[image]

When I analyze through the internet browser if it is connecting the javascript file I realize that it does not connect.

[image]

Are two javascript files

```
<script th:src="@{/javascripts/upload.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/javascripts/uikit.min.js}"></script>
```

However he did not see this

```
<script th:src="@{/javascripts/upload.min.js}"></script>
```

I believe the problem is in the IDE tool

need help!

[This is my repository](https://github.com/wladyband/upload/blob/master/upload/src/main/resources/templates/CadastroFoto.html)